# using where filter with an object in ionic and loopback

Tags: angular, ionic2, loopback

My database is something like this

```
“status”: “todo”, 
“author”: { 
  “username”: “henro92”, 
  “email”: "henry.unah@rocketmail.com", 
  “id”: “5a8aeb6b687d1b041471e4cc” 
},
“source”: { 
  “username”: “h82”, 
  “email”: "henry.unah@gmail.com", 
  “id”: “5a71cb7637b4492704006e47”, 
  “firstname”: “Henry”, 
  “lastname”: “Jordan”, 
  “sex”: " Male ", 
  “dateOfBirth”: “2018-01-31” 
}
```

I want to get find the data by the source which is an object like this and it doesn’t work

```
this.questionnaireresponseapi.findOne({
  where: {
    source:
    this.loopbackauth.getCurrentUserData().user 
  }
})
```

when I try with the status which is a string it works

```
this.questionnaireresponseapi.findOne({
  where: {
    source: this.loopbackauth.getCurrentUserData().user 
  }
})
```

Any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using source.id 
this.questionnaireresponseapi.findOne({where: {'source.id': this.loopbackauth.getCurrentUserId()}}).subscribe((data)=>{
           this.thequestionnaireResponse = data;

}